# Does Fabric JS support .hdr image formats?

Tags: fabricjs, hdr

I need to use ".hdr" images to sketch and draw and do such basic features on top of them. And wanted to know if fabric js will support the .hdr file format ? I could not find anything useful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did as I could not find anything useful. I used Three js with the RGBELoader to handle the .hdr files. This gives a good starting point https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltfloader-and-rgbeloader-adding-hdr-texture-to-enviroment/36086. And for the sketching features, I plan to take the canvas context and pass that to the fabric js and do the sketchings on top of that.